# Nuxt multiple dynamic page param /slug

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a `/post/:id` route that works and I need to create a `/post/:id:/edit` route. How do I do this with Nuxt's dynamic pages setup. This is what my `pages` directory looks like:

```
└── pages
    └── post
        └── _id.vue
```

Documentation does not seem to mention this case, how do I do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directories can be `_id` too, change `_id.vue` to `index.vue` like:

```
└── pages
    └── post
        └── _id
            └── index.vue
            └── edit.vue
```

Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-wozniak-ekpw3